# Line graph disappears after new line is added

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I am having trouble uploading a large .csv file to my HIGHCHART graph. I've been able to graph an 85KB up to 1486 lines by 9 (I) columns. Here is an example:

```
TimeStamp Temp_1_01 Temp_1_02 Temp_2_01 Temp_2_02 Temp_3_01 Temp_3_02 Temp_4_01 Temp_4_02
5/15/2014, 3:25 408 487 63  84  67  91  63  78
5/15/2014 3:30  408 487 63  84  67  91  63  78
5/15/2014 3:35  407 489 63  84  67  91  63  78
5/15/2014 3:40  408 488 63  84  67  91  63  78
5/15/2014 3:44  408 488 63  84  67  91  63  78
...
5/22/2014 9:40  483 421 0   93  76  95  72  89
```

When I add a new line the line graph disappears. Any suggestions?

Here is the javascript:

```
 $.get('Dropbox/geo/sites/GC_Room/loveland.csv', function(data)
       {
          // Split the lines
          var lines = data.split('\n');
          var i = 0;
          var csvData = [];





          // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
          $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line)
          {
             csvData[i] = line.split(',');

             i = i + 1;

          });


          var columns = csvData[0];

          var categories = [], series = [];


          for(var colIndex=0,len=columns.length; colIndex<len; colIndex++)
          {
             //first row data as series's name
             var seriesItem=
             {
                data:[],
                name:csvData[0][colIndex]
             };

             for(var rowIndex=1,rowCnt=csvData.length; rowIndex<rowCnt; rowIndex++)
             {
                //first column data as categories,
                if (colIndex == 0)
                {
                   categories.push(csvData[rowIndex][0]);
                }
                else if(parseFloat(csvData[rowIndex][colIndex])) // <-- here
                {
                   seriesItem.data.push(parseFloat(csvData[rowIndex][colIndex])); 
                }
             };
             //except first column
             if(colIndex>0)series.push(seriesItem);
          }         



          // Create the chart
          var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(
          {
             chart:
             {
                alignTick: false,
                renderTo: 'LANE_METALS',
                type: 'line'

             },
             title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: LANE METALS',
                    x: -20
                },



             xAxis: 
             {  
                categories: categories,
                labels:

               {
                  step: 200,
                   text: 'Time',
                },
                tickWidth: 0
             },
             yAxis: 
             {
                        title: {
                        text: 'Temperature (\xB0C)'
                    },
                min: 0
             },
             tooltip:
             {
                formatter: function()
                {
                   return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+ this.x +': '+ this.y +'\xB0C';
                }
             },
             legend:
             {
                layout: 'vertical',
                //backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                //floating: true,
                align: 'left',
                //x: 100,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                //y: 70,
                borderWidth: 0
             },

             plotOptions:
             {
                area:
                {
                   turboThreshold: 0,
                   stacking: 'normal',
                   lineColor: '#666666',
                   lineWidth: 1,
                   marker:
                   {
                      lineWidth: 1,
                      lineColor: '#666666'
                   }
                }
             },
             series: series
          });

       });
```

Comment: So an input file with 1487 lines causes the graph to vanish? Can you step through with the debugger and determine where in the script the crash occurs?

Comment: IN case when it works with smaller amount of lines, but with huge data not, you need to increase turboThreshold parameter.

Comment: yes @Henry Keiter, when I add line 1487 the graph disappears and the background turns gray. This is the file: [link](http://geoinc.org/Dropbox/geo/sites/GC_Room/loveland.csv)

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian Bochan, Strikers suggested the same thing, but I don't know where to put the plotOptions in my script.

Comment: You have already defined plotOptions, so add the line about threshold in your plotOptions->area etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue can be because of `turboThreshold`

by default turboThreshold is set to 1000. if the points are more than turbo threshold chart will not be plotted.

you can diagonise this by trying to render points less than 1000 and points more than 1000.

so set

```
plotOptions: {
   series: {
       turboThreshold: 10000
   }
}
```

if you are not going to have values more than 10000.
This should work. try once.

Comment: thanks @strikers. What exactly am I replacing from my script to insert this? Do I replace the plotOptions block entirely and encapsulate "series" with it too?

Comment: in plotOptions->area itself keep turbothreshold a very big number.